# A variable call returns value 'undefined' outside of a subscriber function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components, angular9

A similar question to this has been asked previously and received quite a lot of responses and i might sound repetitive to someone, but it's just that am in desperate need of a third eye. I am assigning a value to a variable inside a subscriber function in angular but the variable returns 'undefined' when called outside of the Subscribe function. This is what am doing:

```js
    this.invoiceService.buildDataForDiscountGraph(this.usrId, this.currentYear)
      .subscribe( response => {
        this.discountsGraphData += response;
        //this.discountGraphData is of type 'string'
    });
```

```
This.discountsGraphData
```

returns the desired value when called within the subscriber, but outside of the subscriber, in another function, and even my template it's an empty string.

This is the look of the buildDataForDiscountGraph() function:

```js
buildDataForDiscountGraph(u,y){
    return this.getUserInvoices(u)
      .pipe(
        map(response  => {
          if(Object.keys(response).length > 0)
          {
            let jan = 0, feb = 0, mar = 0, apr = 0;
            let may = 0, june = 0, july = 0, aug = 0;
            let sep = 0, oct = 0, nov = 0, dec = 0;

            for(let x = 0; x < Object.keys(response).length; x++) {
              let dateSplit = response[x]['datecreated'].split('-');
              let year = dateSplit[0];
              let month = dateSplit[1];

              if(y == year){
                if(month == '01')jan += response[x]['discount'];
                if(month == '02')feb += response[x]['discount'];
                if(month == '03')mar += response[x]['discount'];
                if(month == '04')apr += response[x]['discount'];
                if(month == '05')may += response[x]['discount'];
                if(month == '06')june += response[x]['discount'];
                if(month == '07')july += response[x]['discount'];
                if(month == '08')aug += response[x]['discount'];
                if(month == '09')sep += response[x]['discount'];
                if(month == '10')oct += response[x]['discount'];
                if(month == '11')nov += response[x]['discount'];
                if(month == '12')dec += response[x]['discount'];
              }
            }

            return [
              jan, feb, mar, apr, may, june, july, aug,
              sep, oct, nov, dec
            ].join();
          }  
      })
    )
  }
```

I had to move the code into my service in an attempt to figure out what is causing it. The Service function getUserInvoices() calls an endpoint like so;

```js
/**
   * Get Invoices
   *
   * @param userId
   * @param Limit
   * @param Offset
   */
  getUserInvoices(usrId, limit?, offset?){
    return this.http.get(this.apiEndPoint + usrId + '/invoices?limit=' + limit + '&offset=' + offset)
      .pipe(
        map( data =>
          {
            return (data ? data : []);
          }
        )
      )
  }
```

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz for this ?

Comment: Editor Url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqnis3

Comment: you are accessing discountsGraphData variable before it gets the value from the buildDataForDiscountGraph function

Comment: What's the ideal way to access the discountGraphData variable, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can set this.discountGraphData outside the subscriber using function

```
this.invoiceService.buildDataForDiscountGraph(this.usrId, this.currentYear)
  .subscribe( response => {
      this.setDate(response);
    //this.discountsGraphData += response;
    //this.discountGraphData is of type 'string'
});

setDate(data){
    this.discountsGraphData = data;
    console.log(this.discountsGraphData);  --> you will get value here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Above works, but this does not: `setDate(data){
    this.discountsGraphData = data;
}     console.log(this.discountsGraphData);  --> you will get value here.`

Comment: shouldn't i be able to call this.discountsGraphData from another function? That is after setting it like you suggest?

Comment: if you want data before page load then use resolver and you will get data and once you set the value for this.discountsGraphData you can use the value in any function of that controller